# post_generation with factory boy gives ManyRelatedManager when I wanted list

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm clearly being a numpty, I will admit that at the very start. I'm using the following factory

```
class DataSheetFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.myModel
        django_get_or_create = ('key_field',)

    key_field = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    ... <additional fields>
    @factory.post_generation
    def product_contributors(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
             return
        if extracted:
            for person in extracted:
                self.product_contributors.add(person)
```

When I create this with `PDS=DataSheetFactory(product_contributors= (<tuple of users>))` I expect a list of users in the field `product_contributors`, but I get a `django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager` instead, so the tests won't work. What was I supposed to do, as I followed the "Common Recipes" [here](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html)?

Just to clarify, I am asking how to use factory boy to create a list of users in a many-to-many field of a model. I tried what was suggested in the docs, and I get a `ManyRelatedManager`, not a list, so `factory_boy` generates unusable instances.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. `product_contributors` can't be both a method and a list that you call `add` on.

Comment: @DanielRoseman this is confusing because magic in factoryboy means this isn't really an instance method and `self` here is actually the instance of the Django model, rather than of the factory.  I usually name that kwarg `obj` instead of `self` in my code

Comment: @DavidBoshton it is normal to get a `ManyRelatedManager` when you access a many-to-many field on a Django model instance. if you want the related objects as a list you need to do `PDS.product_contributors.all()` (this will only work if you are using `create` strategy rather than `build` since it is a db query)

Comment: Ok, so how do I create an instance of my model with that field being a list of items upon which I can simply plug into my code? My code expects that field to be a list of users, not a `ManyRelatedManager`

Comment: @DavidBoshton sounds like your code is the problem, then. You get the list by doing `.all()` on the manager.

Comment: @Anentropic ah OK fair enough. Seems like OP's code is missing the relevant decorator though, don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: it is weird to want your factory-created model instances to have an attribute that's not on your non-factory-created model instances... I mean if your other code expects that field to be a list of users maybe your other code is wrong, not the factory

Comment: @Anentropic It is a field in the model. It is a many-to-many field, and I understand from the docs that you use the `postgeneration` tool as referenced. If I want to add a group of users in that field, I need to do it after the initial instance is generated. So how should I be populating that field in factory_boy?

Comment: @DavidBoshton if it is a many-to-many field on the model then you are populating it correctly in your factory, it is your other code that is wrong to expect a list

Comment: Ah, yes. I understand now. This is the first time I have dealt with one of these and the first time I have used models with ManyToMany in. Thanks, @Anentropic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed above, your issue comes from the magic I've put into factory_boy: the `self` in a `@post_generation` isn't the factory instance, but the actual object just generated.

Thus, the `product_contributors` is indeed an instance of Django's "RelatedManager", you can access the items with:

```
datasheet = DataSheetFactory()
contributors = datasheet.product_contributors.all()
```